# Caching and serving pre-rendered vector tiles in pbf format

Tags: vector, tilestache, vector-tiles

I want to serve vector tiles server in pbf format. For that I used [Mapnik-vector-tiles](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile) which is bundled by [avecado](https://github.com/MapQuest/avecado/). Using avecado_server i can render pbf tiles on the fly using

> ./avecado_server -b 2 test/xml/vector_imposm_nocollect.xml 7789

But the full planet avecado_server is not sufficient to server on the fly because it takes more time to render each tile.
So I need pre-render tiles using ./avecado and cache it in disk and server those cached tiles with separate server.

Avecado generate tiles in pbf format.

For this I prefer to go with [Tile Stache](https://github.com/opensciencemap/TileStache) but I didn't know how to use [Tile Stache](https://github.com/opensciencemap/TileStache) for this scenario.

What is the best way to cache and serve the pre-rendered tiles?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for this page: [This page lists implementations of software that work with vector tiles using the Mapbox protobuf format.](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/wiki/Implementations)